# In my case how can I show Unity Ad every 3 times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make my players watch an ad every 3 times they lose.
I know there are similar problems and the solutions to it on the internet, but I tried and it didn't help me in my case.

Could you please help?

This is what I have so far:

```
[System.Obsolete]
    void Start()
    {
        Monetization.Initialize(store_id, true);
    }
[System.Obsolete]
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision info)
    {
        if (info.collider.tag == "Obstacle3")
        {
            if (Monetization.IsReady(video_ad))
            {
                ShowAdPlacementContent ad1 = null;
                ad1 = Monetization.GetPlacementContent(video_ad) as ShowAdPlacementContent;

                if (ad1 != null)
                {
                    ad1.Show();
                }

            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What part of this doesn't work? You might want to move the mod check to the enclosing if so you don't do work every time that you only need to do 1/3 of the time.

Comment: The part with checking loadCount: `if (loadCount % 3 == 0 && ad1 != null)
                {
                    ad1.Show();
                }
                loadCount++;` Thats what I think, I might be wrong

Comment: Well, use the debugger or add some logs and narrow it down. There are a number of things that could be going wrong but nothing obvious stands out to me. You will need to debug this.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica Oh, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

```
static int count = 0;

if (ad1 != null){

     if(count == 4)
     {

       count = 0;
       ad1.Show();

     } else {

     count++;

     }

}
```

Full Code:

```
[System.Obsolete]
   static int count = 0;

    [System.Obsolete]
    void Start()
    {
        Monetization.Initialize(store_id, true);
    }

    [System.Obsolete]
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision info)
    {
        if (info.collider.tag == "Obstacle3")
        {
            if (Monetization.IsReady(video_ad))
            {
                ShowAdPlacementContent ad1 = null;
                ad1 = Monetization.GetPlacementContent(video_ad) as ShowAdPlacementContent;

                if (ad1 != null)
                {
                    if(count == 4)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        ad1.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count++;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: You should reset the counter to `0` after showing an add otherwise it fails after reaching `2147483647` :D

Comment: @derHugo Thanks! I fixed it